# Condition density of random variables with Weibull distribution

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, density-function

This is from the book introduction to Heavy-Tailed & sub exponential distribution by Foss.
$F_α(x)=e^{−x^{α} } , x≥0, (1.7) $ and hence density $f_α(x)=αx^{α−1} e^{−x^{α} } , x ≥ 0, $ for some shape parameter $α > 0.$
 " Let $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$ be independent random variables with common Weibull distribution function $F_α$ as given by (1.7). We consider the distribution of the random variable $\frac{ξ_1} {d} $conditional on the sum $ξ_1 +ξ_2 = d$ for varying values of d and the shape parameter $α$. This conditional distribution has density $g_{α,d}$ where $g_{α,d} (z)=c[z(1−z)]^{α−1} e^{−d^{α} (z^{α} +(1−z)^{α} )} , (1.8)$ for the appropriate normalising constant c"
 I want to know how this conditional density is derived?                                                                     Shouldn't there be a denominator for marginal density?    How come the answer is just the product of two densities? –

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange! Please provide a bit more or your own work in the question. Can you write down the Weibull distribution? Can you compute a conditional density function in general?

Comment: Notice that you can edit your question. I would suggest you add these details there rather in comments only.

Comment: I am aware that Conditional density = joint PDF /marginal,  but how is above answer from derived from this?

Comment: It would be better if you type out the relevant distribution functions/densities using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Have completely formatted using math jax. Please see if anyone can help.  TIA